# Minimum permissions needed to allow PHP PDO / Apache access to SQLite database in /var/www

Tags: sqlite, permissions, pdo, apache

**SOLVED:** See my answer below

I'm experiencing the same issue that Austin Hyde experienced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319112/pdo-sqlite-read-only-database).  I have an SQLite database that I can read, but not write.

Specifically, I'm getting **General error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database in /var/www/html/green/database.php on line 34**

My issue diverges from his as follows:

-As recommended in the answers to his question, I've made the database world-writeable, as well as the folder in which the database resides, with no luck.  I've also set the owner of the database to "apache" as well as "nobody", without success.

-I've set the entire path set 777, beginning at /var (which I hate to do), no joy.

-I've messed about with SELinux (I'm running Fedora 12) to let httpd do whatever it wants; nothing.

I feel that I'm almost certainly missing something simple here, but I'm out of ideas.

**What permissions need to be on an SQLite file in order to allow PHP / Apache to read and write to it via PDO?**

Edit: Another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039218/why-can-i-use-select-but-not-insert-on-a-sqlite-database-in-php), adding weight to the hypothesis that I've got a write permissions conflict somewhere.

Comment: Preemptive disclaimer: I checked the FAQ's for both serverfault and superuser before posting here and neither one seemed like the appropriate place for this question.  However, I'm not opposed to migration if it'll get me better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who can not afford to disable `SELinux` entirely, here is the way to go.

To make a directory (say `rw_data`) and all it's content writable to any process running in `httpd_t` domain type ie. web-server processes, use following command as `root`.

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t "/var/www/html/mysite/rw_data/"
```

you can check `SELinux` context labels with following command :

```
ls -Z /var/www/html/mysite | grep httpd_sys_content_rw_t
```

This works on `Fedora 16`, should work on other `SELinux` enabled `distros` too.

Comment: httpd_sys_content_rw_t is erroneous, it's httpd_sys_rw_content_t actually. Additionally, chcon is useless as that information will be lost after the first SELinux upgrade when restorecon is run on the system. Use semanage instead, e.g. semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/html/mysite/rw_data(/.*)?"